# Problem creating multiple child processes

Tags: linux, shell, process

Im new at process creation etc..so probably a basic question.
Im creating a fixed number of child processes, each doing nothing but printing their pid. The problem is in the output that i get. Have a look:

```
int main(){  
pid_t pid=0;  
int i=0,status=0;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
            pid=fork();
            switch(pid){
                    case 0:{        //Child
                            printf("\nChild pid: %d",getpid());
                            exit(0);
                            break;
                            }
                    case -1: {//Error
                            printf("Error occured in fork");
                            exit(1);
                            break;
                            }
                    default:{
                            printf("\nParent id: %d",getpid());
                            printf("\nIts child id: %d",pid);
                            wait(NULL);
                            }
            }
```

Output:
`Child pid: 1450

    Parent id: 1445

    Its child id: 1450

    Child pid: 1455Its child id: 1450

    Parent id: 1445

    Its child id: 1455

    Child pid: 1460Its child id: 1455

    Parent id: 1445

    Its child id: 1460`
The problem is I dont know why only the second print statement of the parent process is appearing and not the first, if any at all. I know im not waiting for my child processes to end( frankly i dont know how i would do that), but if the parent does execute before ending its child processes, why arent both its print statements appearing, and why is the `\n` being ignored in that line too.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thx.

Update:If i replace `wait(NULL)` with `printf("\n%d\n",wait(NULL))` It gives me a perfect output, without stray prints. Any idea what couldve fixed it? After all they both do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there are several processes writing to the same file (your console) at the same time without any concurrency control or any lock. That, and that the ttys are strange creatures, at best, make weird things happens. Over that, remember that `printf` is buffered.

Your output should be read this way:

```
Child pid: 1450    <- Child #1
Parent id: 1445    <- Parent #1.1
Its child id: 1450 <- Parent #1.2

Child pid: 1455[Its child id: 1450] <- Child #2 with garbage at the end
Parent id: 1445                     <- Parent #2.1
Its child id: 1455                  <- Parent #2.2

Child pid: 1460[Its child id: 1455] <- Child #3 with garbage at the end
Parent id: 1445                     <- Parent #3.2
Its child id: 1460                  <- Parent #3.2
```

You could try redirecting the output to a file, and see if not being a tty makes any difference.

Anyway, to do it the right wat, you should use any mechanism that guarantees multiprocess correctness.

**UPDATE**

Yes, now I see it. You have the '\n' at the beginning of your printing lines, not at the end, as is usual. Stdout is normally line-buffered, that means that the buffer is flushed to the device when it sees a '\n'. And since you have them at the beginning there is always one line in the buffer waiting for output.

Now, when you `fork` your process the output buffer gets duplicated and the last line from the parent is printed by the child (why it is printed *after*, and not before, is still a mystery to me).

Anyway, the new `printf` you added has a '\n' at the end, so it flushes the buffer, `fork` finds it empty and all goes fine. You could as well call `fflush(stdout)` but it is cumbersome.

The morale of the story is: "When you `printf` for debugging purposes **always** put a `\n` at the end of every line or you can get partial, mixed contents.

Comment: ok..so wouldnt waiting for child processes help in anyway? If that would, could you also explain how would i do that?

Comment: But you *are* waiting, look at the `wait()` function call. Having the child pid, I personally prefer the `waitpid()`, just in case.

Comment: yes i did put that, but i didnt really know if that was put at the right place or if itll work even..thx anyways.

Comment: Well, the right place depends on what you want to do, but seems correct to me. You can check if it worked looking at the return value of `wait()`: it should be the pid of the ending process.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is buffering and flushing of stdout.

Both lines are being printed, but not flushed to output at the time you expect.... depening on where the output is going to, (file, pipe, terminal, stderr etc) printf uses different buffer strategies.

I guess that in your case it only flushes on newline (check `man setbuf`)

Move the newline to the end of the rather than in the beginning, so for example....

```
       printf("Parent id: %d\n",getpid());
       printf("Its child id: %d\n",pid);
```

And be consistent with alway putting the \n at the end of printf for all your printfs.