# Shell install script moves command prompt to the right when done

Tags: bash, shell, sh

In [installation script](https://github.com/virtualmin/virtualmin-install/blob/master/virtualmin-install.sh) for Virtualmin, the command prompt is moved/shifted sideways to the right a lot, when the script is finished. It's hard for me to understand why this is happening?

Does anyone have a clue how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Because the command just finished wrote some text (potentially spaces) and no new line at the end. Then, the prompt appears after this set of spaces.

Comment: Yes, sure but what if we don't want new lines in the progress. Is there a solution to that?

Comment: Errr... probably I will say something obvious but: if you don't want new lines somewhere, remove them from whatever they are, so they are not printed when executed.

Comment: The actual fix was simple enough https://github.com/virtualmin/slib/commit/a25e9590322aa6dfe3d8866695ac5310d6a6a0d9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are facing the same symptom as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538581/problem-creating-multiple-child-processes/7538692#7538692), where for each installation task, a child process seems to be forked to print progress information such as a green-background check mark. (Or a child process to print those check marks for all the tasks)

The evidence is clear: the indentation of your new prompt locates exactly at the same place ready to print a green-background check mark.

Probably you need to check which child process is left there printing those indents.